# Como ordenar uma p:dataTable

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, classificação, datatable

Como faço para ordenar uma datatable por um texto.
Por exemplo meu sistema é um sistema de ordem de serviços, preciso que as ordens "Em Aberto" venham primeiro. Segue o codigo da datatable abaixo.
tentei usar o sortby mais não me deu resultado.

Este é meu listarTodos:

```
public List<Ordens> listarTodos() { 
String sql = "select o from Ordens as o inner join o.usuario as u where u.id " 
           + " = "+UserStatic.getUsuario().getId();
```

Preciso ordenar por esta coluna:

```
<p:column filterBy="#{b.situacao}" headerText="Situação Técnico" sortBy="#{b.situacao}" style="width: 98px;"> <h:outputText value="#{b.situacao}" style=" color: red"/> </p:column>
```

a situação 'Em Aberto' tem que vir primeiro.

talvez ordenar no sql daria certo, mais não sei como fazer no sql, se alguem souber.
Tentei assim mais não deu certo

```
    public List<Ordens> listarTodos() {
    String sql = "select o from Ordens as o inner join o.usuario as u where      u.id"
            + " = "+UserStatic.getUsuario().getId()
            +"order by o.situacao DESC";
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Você usou a área de comentários para adicionar esclarecimentos ou fazer uma pergunta. Em vez disso, é melhor [edit] a sua pergunta e incluir esse conteúdo lá mesmo. Para isso, existe um link de [edit] em baixo da pergunta. Assim, o conteúdo fica todo reunido em um único lugar, e quem chegar aqui não precisa ficar procurando informações em vários comentários para entender o problema.

Comment: Postei o código logo acima.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complementando a resposta do @Rafael, você também pode usar a tag sortBy dentro do dataTable para o dado aparecer ordenado ao usuário sem a necessidade de clickar na coluna para ordenar.

```
    <p:dataTable sortBy="{ordem.status}"
                 var="ordem">
            <p:column headerText="Status" sortBy="#{ordem.status}">
                  <h:outputText value="#{ordem.status}" />
            </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

Caso você queira mostrar sua tabela já ordenada você tem que ordenar sua lista de objetos da tabela antes de mostra-la.

Ou

adicione o `sortBy` na coluna da tabela:

```
<p:column headerText="Status" sortBy="#{ordem.status}">
      <h:outputText value="#{ordem.status}" />
</p:column>
```

Comment: O problema seria que o sortBy tenho que clicar para ordenar.. Essa tela fica em um monitor, teria que ordenar automático. Como eu ordeno a lista de objetos ? poderia me auxiliar ?

Comment: Adicionar um order by na sua query sql, para trazer ordenados por Em Aberto

Comment: Não entendo muito de sql.
ficaria assim ?
"select o from Ordens as o inner join o.usuario as u where u.id
order by situacao = 'Em Aberto' "

Comment: `order by o.status DESC` ou `order by o.status ASC`, para decrescente ou crescente. Você tem que mandar a coluna não valor, segue exemplo de order by , http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: Coloquei meu codigo na descrição como está agora.. e nao deu certo